# undesired bottom padding in a table cell

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <title>Moravský kras</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="border-spacing: 0px">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

With this simple code, I get some bottom-padding in the table cell under the image (at least in firefox/chrome). Please, tell me how can I get rid of it. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWwTu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the `img` being `inline` by nature. Make it `block`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <title>Moravský kras</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="border-spacing: 0px">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="display: block;"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ZWwTu/1/

---

#### Explanation

The image element is one such element, which has both the nature of appearing `inline` as well as having a box model. So, it is kind of something to do with `vertical-align`ment. When you give `block` display, it treats as a regular box model. This is just my view.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you, please, just explain a bit more why this happens with inline elements?